# R summary function and times

Tags: r, time, summary

How can the R summary function summarize time values represented as HH:MM:SS strings?

For instance, when importing the following CSV file:

```
    name,time
name-a,1:00:00
name-b,1:15:00
name-c,1:30:00
name-d,1:45:00
name-e,2:00:00
```

The default use of the summary function "only" lists the HH:MM:SS times as different strings.

```
> summary(times)
         name        time  
     name-a:1   1:00:00:1  
     name-b:1   1:15:00:1  
     name-c:1   1:30:00:1  
     name-d:1   1:45:00:1  
     name-e:1   2:00:00:1
```

I would like the summary function to understand the times as HH:MM:SS time values and display a summary similar to the following one:

```
> summary(times)
time
Min.   :1:00:00
1st Qu.:1:15:00
Median :1:30:00  
Mean   :1:30:00
3rd Qu.:1:45:00
Max.   :2:00:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `chron` package and its `times` function.

```
times$time<-times(times$time)
summary(times)
#    name        time         
#name-a:1   Min.   :01:00:00  
#name-b:1   1st Qu.:01:15:00  
#name-c:1   Median :01:30:00  
#name-d:1   Mean   :01:30:00  
#name-e:1   3rd Qu.:01:45:00  
#           Max.   :02:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the 'time' column is stored as a string, R cannot compute any summary statistic on it.
Just convert your timestamp into any proper time format.

```
library(lubridate)

times <- data.frame(name = c("name-a",
                             "name-b",
                             "name-c",
                             "name-d",
                             "name-e"),
                    time = c("1:00:00",
                             "1:15:00",
                             "1:30:00",
                             "1:45:00",
                             "2:00:00"))

times$time <- hms(times$time)
summary(times)
```

Outputs:

```
 > summary(times)
     name        time          
 name-a:1   Min.   :1H 0M 0S   
 name-b:1   1st Qu.:1H 15M 0S  
 name-c:1   Median :1H 30M 0S  
 name-d:1   Mean   :1H 30M 0S  
 name-e:1   3rd Qu.:1H 45M 0S  
            Max.   :2H 0M 0S
```

Here I use the lubridate package as an example but there are other options (check ?as.POSIXct or ?strptime)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `strptime` function and then use `summary(times)`

```
>times$time = strptime(times$time,%H:%M:%S")
> summary(times)
 name        time                    
 name-a:1   Min.   :2015-10-21 01:00:00  
 name-b:1   1st Qu.:2015-10-21 01:15:00  
 name-c:1   Median :2015-10-21 01:30:00  
 name-d:1   Mean   :2015-10-21 01:30:00  
 name-e:1   3rd Qu.:2015-10-21 01:45:00  
            Max.   :2015-10-21 02:00:00
```

Comment: OP only want time, no date.